# Is it possible to Change local URL

Tags: javascript, html, url, dynamic

Is this possible to change the local URL of your current page.

Like in JavaScript:

```js
<script>
function click()
{
  location.replace("http://google.com");
}
</script>
```

Using this code we will visit google.com but What I want to do is not to visit the URL just want to change it locally?

I mean :

```
mysite.com
```

I want to change URL to

```
wordpress.com
```

but don't want to visit wordpress.com

Comment: what url do you want to change to? also what do you mean by change it locally i dont get it give an example

Comment: I believe that's generally called phishing.

Comment: Yup that can be used as phishing

Comment: Would YOU want someone to be able to make you think you were on `chase.com` when you were really on `im-trying-to-scam-you.com`? Sorry, but I hope you never find a way to do this.

Comment: I don't really want to do that just want to know is it possible using php shell commands or anything else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. You can only change to same origin urls. It's a security feature implemented in most browsers.

You can read more information about same origin policy [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).